# OCaml Binary Tree

Tags: tree, ocaml, binary-tree, traversal, inorder

Pass the function below through this [Binary Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMP8x.png):

```
let rec inorder(t:tree) : int list =
  begin match t with
    | Empty -> []
    | Node (left, x, right) -> inorder left @ (x :: inorder right)
   end
```

Why is the result [1;2;3;4;5;6;7] and not [1;2;3;4;5;7;6] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, 7 does come before 6 in the tree diagram you linked to.

What does the actual data look like that is passed to the `inorder` function?

Comment: The tree was actually given in a problem set - maybe the answer key was wrong then